# How can I select rows from a table that don't exist in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables - first table holds all unique data (columns: title, artist, album). The second table has repeated data or people listening daily to an rss feed.

I want to save all the data from table2 to table1, but only if the row of table2 doesn't exist in table1.  I want a sql query which will return all rows of table2 that aren't in table1 -
how?

Comment: If you want help with an exact query you should at least post the relevant parts of the schema. Please provide a bit more detail if you'd like people to help you.

Comment: You'll have to provide the list of columns in table2, and explain how to determine if a table2 row exists in table1

Comment: How is "only if the row of table2 doesn't exist in table1" determined? Do the columns title, artist and album exist in table2? Is it that you want to append all rows from table2 where that same combination of title, artist and album do not exist in table1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this, probably:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
(columns)
SELECT columns
FROM Table1
WHERE Table2.UniqueColumn NOT IN (SELECT UniqueColumn FROM Table1)
```

?

Comment: no i want select command of everything in table2 that doesn't exist in table1 and table1 can contain other fields but the fields to check must be artist album and title

Comment: thank you again im exited i never saw an sql like this before :)

Comment: No problem. If you want to get more serious about SQL you should check out the basic syntax. The stuff here is pretty standard.

Comment: a question say table2 have 2 unique rows will it insert all 2 or just the first row?

Comment: It will insert any rows in Table2 which do not match the set from the SELECT in Table1.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the columns `title, artist, album` exist in Table2 and that you want to add all rows from Table2 where the given combination of those three do not exist in Table1, you can do something like:

```
Insert Table1( title, artist, album, ... )
Select title, artist, album, ...
From Table2
Where ( title, artist, album ) Not In   (
                                        Select title, artist, album
                                        From Table1
                                        )
```

Comment: a question say table2 have 2 unique rows will it insert all 2 or just the first row?

Comment: @prx - If you have two rows in Table2 with the same set of keys which do not exist in Table1, both will be added. If Table1 has a unique or primary key constraint on those three columns, it will throw an error. If that is a problem, there are a couple of solutions. One solution is to use a Group By query that groups on the three values. The safer choice is to only insert one of the duplicate rows but requires you have a column of unique integer values (e.g. auto_increment column). I can show you but do you have such a column?